# Filtering out words that don't match sequence when user types in text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a list of names, and every time the user types in text, it should filter the names to only show the ones that match the text that the user typed in. When the user clicks the clear button, it should clear the input and show all the names again.

So I made an array of names to show up in a div. The problem is that the first time it goes through all the names, it filters perfectly (at every keyup event, it loops through all the names to check...). The second time it loops through (the second letter the user types in), it doesn't remove the words anymore... Can somebody help me solve the problem?

Also, when I click the clear button, it clears the screen and puts back all the words from the array, but it doesn't work anymore—it doesn't remove words...

This is my code in my javascript file:

```
words = ["MARY", "PATRICIA", "LINDA", "BARBARA", "ELIZABETH", "JENNIFER", "MARIA", "SUSAN"]
window.addEventListener("load", CreateWords);
function CreateWords() {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        newP = document.createElement('p');
        newP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words[i]));
        var div = document.getElementById("wordDiv");
        div.appendChild(newP);
        newP.style.fontSize = 20;
        newP.id = words[i];
    }
}

var lettersTyped = document.getElementById("userInput");
lettersTyped.addEventListener("keyup", filterWords);
var clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton");
clearButton.addEventListener("click", ClearScreen);

function filterWords() {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var val = words[i].toLocaleLowerCase().search(lettersTyped.value);

        if (val == -1) {
            var child = document.getElementById(words[i]);
            child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        }
    }
}

function ClearScreen() {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        newP = document.createElement('p');
        newP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words[i]));
        var div = document.getElementById("wordDiv");
        div.appendChild(newP);
        newP.style.fontSize = 20;
        newP.id = words[i];
    }
    lettersTyped.value = " ";
}
```

Comment: the second time through your code will error out on child.parentNode.removeChild(child) if you've already removed elements on the first keyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly minimal fix.

1. I got rid of `CreateWords` and just used `ClearScreen` instead.
2. I set `wordDiv`'s `innerHTML` to `""` at the top of `ClearScreen` to avoid seeing duplicate entries. (Your code always adds all the words again, even if some are already there.)
3. I guarded `child.parentNode` with an `if (child)` so it doesn't break when the word is already filtered out.
4. I set `lettersTyped.value` to `""` instead of `" "`. (The space was probably breaking things for you.)
5. I used `indexOf` instead of `search`, since you want to match the exact string, not a regular expression.

Here's my completed code:

```
words = ["MARY", "PATRICIA", "LINDA", "BARBARA", "ELIZABETH", "JENNIFER", "MARIA", "SUSAN"]
window.addEventListener("load", ClearScreen);

var lettersTyped = document.getElementById("userInput");
lettersTyped.addEventListener("keyup", filterWords);
var clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton");
clearButton.addEventListener("click", ClearScreen);

function filterWords() {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var val = words[i].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(lettersTyped.value);

        if (val === -1) {
            var child = document.getElementById(words[i]);
            if (child) {
                child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

function ClearScreen() {
    document.getElementById("wordDiv").innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        newP = document.createElement('p');
        newP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words[i]));
        newP.style.fontSize = 20;
        newP.id = words[i];
        var div = document.getElementById("wordDiv");
        div.appendChild(newP);
    }
    lettersTyped.value = "";
    lettersTyped.focus();
}
```

Note that there are still some issues with this code. E.g. if you type "mary" and then delete the Y to get "mar", you probably want "MARIA" to show up again. Also, you probably want comparisons to be case-insensitive. (If you type a capital M, it shouldn't filter out "MARY".)

**EDIT**

A more complete fix, taking into account the other issues I called out. Note that I've gotten rid of the "clear" button altogether, since now the user can just delete their input to see the full list again.

```
words = ["MARY", "PATRICIA", "LINDA", "BARBARA", "ELIZABETH", "JENNIFER", "MARIA", "SUSAN"];

function filter() {
    document.getElementById("wordDiv").innerHTML = "";
    var typed = document.getElementById("userInput").value.toLocaleLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(typed) !== -1) {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words[i]));
            document.getElementById("wordDiv").appendChild(p);
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", filter);
document.getElementById("userInput").addEventListener("keyup", filter);
```

Comment: thanks a billion! now it works perfectly.I'm very new in programming so everything is so hard for me. thanks again for your help.

Comment: just one little question to better understand-why when the form loads, the index of all the words are 0 and therefore the words go on the screen? the user didn't type in anything yet and i thought that it checks according to user input? thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this help? `"hello".indexOf("") === 0` So when the user hasn't typed anything, the test passes for all words.